# MYSQL: How to insert rows in a table based on a condition of other two tables

Tags: mysql

The setup is this:

table A has columns desc and date

table B has columns desc, date and task

table C has columns keyid and type.

What I want to do is to copy some of the rows from table B to table A, where A.desc should be B.desc and A.date should be B.date. To select which rows to copy, the logic is this: "All rows such that B.task = C.keyid AND C.type='1'".

If I wanted to SELECT only the rows to copy, the query would be this:

```
SELECT B.desc, B.date FROM B,C WHERE B.task=C.keyid AND C.type='1'
```

The rows resulting from that selection need to be copied to A. I know how to write the select, but how do I write the INSERT INTO query?

Comment: Note that desc is a reserved word in MySQL, making it generally a poor choice for a column/table identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This untested query should work:

```
insert into tableA (tableA.desc, tableA.data) SELECT B.desc, B.date FROM B,C WHERE B.task=C.keyid AND C.type='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run this query:

```
 INSERT INTO A(desc, date) 
    VALUES (
      SELECT B.desc, B.date 
       FROM B,C 
       WHERE B.task=C.keyid AND C.type='1' 
    )
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO table_A (desc, date)
SELECT B.desc, B.date FROM table_B as B,table_C as C WHERE B.task=C.keyid AND C.type='1'
```